# Getting error when trying to get into phpmyadin on Mac

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

I changed the password for the "root" user in phpmyadmin, now i get an error:

MySQL said: Documentation

Cannot connect: invalid settings.

mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

Tried editing the config.inc.php it says i don't have permission to edit.

Tried doing the terminal through xampp and still no luck. Any help?

Comment: *now i get an error* Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71505230/edit) and show us the error.

Comment: *Tried editing the `config.inc.php` it says i don't have permission to edit* You may be facing file permission issues. What results do you get when you run `ls -l  config.inc.php` in the terminal?

Comment: Use the TextEdit app and try editing the file `config.inc.php` most specifically the lines corresponding to `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '...'` and `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '..'`

Comment: i edited the question with the error. I tried editing the file config.inc.php but it says i have to duplicate it, when i do it says i can't save it because i don't have permissions for it.

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l  config.inc.php` ?   Secondly, what's the output of `whoami` ?

Comment: who am i says my username which i know has admin priveliges. The ls -l config.inc.php just says "no such file directory"..i'm not sure how to move into that directory being that it is mapped to an ip address.

Comment: [How to Launch Terminal in the Current Folder Location on Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11323/how-can-i-open-a-terminal-window-directly-from-my-current-finder-location)